# Custom tableview scroll iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

I need to show ***three/ four UI buttons and levels***, ***two image views in a custom cell*** but there is a condition on the basis of that I need to hide an imageView and when it will be hidden, I need to *decrease tableview size and buttons which are below of that image view that will move upward*.

For that I am giving required conditions in

> heightForRowAtIndexPath

and returning cells height accordingly and in tableview

> CellForRowAtIndexPath

method I am hiding imageView and setting buttons positions which are below of that imageView.

The problem is that:
**1) TableView is not scrolling smoothly**

**2) Initially at the time of scrolling down everything is working but when I 
move upward then image is resizing and changing its shape. To solve that I have used AutoLayout but still it is not working.**

I need your expert advice. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to provide some code in order for anyone to give a useful answer. And a screenshot of your prototype cell would also be helpful.